# Difference between random normal variable & a random number

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

What is the difference between drawing 10 random normal variables
& randomly picking 10 numbers
For e.g. if I generate 10 random normal variables & the result is

```
[-0.06349343, -1.16550095, -0.05410842, -0.95035901, -1.60685548,
         0.30827648,  0.0432223 ,  0.66256948, -1.35057285, -1.09169492]
```

I can generate 10 random numbers between -2 & 2 & the same are valid values for a random normal variable.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random variable is a mathematical term used in statistical theory. For example, a mathematical question is; suppose X is a random variable with a standard normal distribution, what is the probability that X > 0. The answer is 50%, or 0.5.

A random number doesn't have this specific scientific meaning. The two words are very close, but the meaning is different because a statistician would never refer to a random variable as a "random number". Now if you use a computer to generate random numbers, you might use these as "samples" or "simulations" of a random variable. You can also use those samples to answer a question. For example, if you generate 1000 random numbers, normally distributed, approximately 50% of them will be > 0.

I cannot make much sense of your other question, on how 10 random numbers between -2 and 2 are "valid values" for a random normal variable. A normally distributed variable has a specific distribution, the "bell shape" that you will encounter if you read about it, but if you generate numbers between -2 and 2, you will never get the same distribution of numbers. So while they are possible outcomes or samples of a normally distributed random variable, you cannot use them to answer questions about that random variable, because they don't follow the full pattern.